# Ubuntu 23.04 video not playing - audio works,VLC works

Tags: video, totem

I'm new to Ubuntu, but used Linux Mint for years. I just installed Ubuntu yesterday. For some reason MP4 videos will not play using the default video application (I am guessing this is totem). The lines move and change color. AVI files are OK. Opening the same MP4 video in VLC plays it correctly.

[image: video garbled]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `totem` and use `vlc` or better, `mpv`.

BTW, `totem` is taking a lot of CPU and MEM.

I think this issue is related to codec of app.

Comment: Not a fan of vlc, I find it clunky. Installed mpv, it works as well. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just note, you can compare `vlc` and `mpv` related to `cpu` and `mem` load, you will be surprised maybe. ;)